# I am getting a TypeError on a Path.cwd() line

Tags: python, excel

I was previously able to run this line of code just fine but I'm not sure whats I did to make it not run anymore. I get an error saying "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". How do I fix this error?

`

```
    f_path = Path.cwd("F:\Parts controller\Claudia-Master Data Collection")  # file in current working directory
```

`

[Picture of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzpnN.png)

I tried changing it to single quotes and doubling the back slash but neither worked.

Comment: Assuming you're using [pathlib.Path.cwd()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.cwd), `cwd()` takes no arguments (takes `self` behind the scenes, that being the "first" argument) and just returns the current working directory. So when you pass in a filepath, it's throws the error because you're not supposed to pas anything into it

Comment: Also, in the future please include the full error traceback as text in the body of the question, not as an image or link

Comment: `self` would be a parameter name, not the argument. (Plus, as `cwd` is a class method, the conventional name for the first parameter would be `cls`.) `Path` is the implicit first argument to `cwd`.

Comment: It's not clear when that line of code would *ever* have run. Did you try to replace `os.chdir` with `Path.cwd`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pathlib.Path.cwd()
```

This is the syntax for retrieval of the **c**urrent **w**orking **d**irectory.
As an argument for Path, you can pass a string with a relative/absolute address, but calling cwd() on any Path will not take that into consideration. Pretty sure you had the address in the *Path* arguments instead of *cwd* before, and that indeed is a valid syntax.